# A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations; I don't think that it is

Tags: sql

I am getting the error 
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.
and I have searched for this error, but I do not understand, where am I assigning (from cursor, right?) and where am I retrieving this value?

If I create a # table before the dynamic code, rewrite the dynamic code to insert into the # table and move the update after the dynamic code, it works.
The problem is that then I need to create like 10 # tables...

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @CurrentYear NVARCHAR(MAX), @ProductId NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE CurrentYearCursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT DISTINCT ProductId, CurrentYear
FROM #SubcategoryProducts;

OPEN CurrentYearCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM CurrentYearCursor
INTO @ProductId, @CurrentYear;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SELECT @SQL =
    N'
WITH KeyCategories AS
(   SELECT DISTINCT MS.CompanyId
  , SP.IndustryName
  , SP.ProductName
  , MS.[' + @CurrentYear + N'] * MS2.[' + @CurrentYear + N'] / 100 AS Size
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MS.CompanyId, SP.IndustryName
                       ORDER BY MS.[' + @CurrentYear + N'] * MS2.[' +     @CurrentYear + N'] / 100 DESC) AS Rn
FROM Sports.dbo.GlobalBrandOwnerContext AS GBOC
INNER JOIN dbo.MarketShare AS MS
    ON GBOC.CompanyId = MS.CompanyId
INNER JOIN #SubcategoryProducts AS SP
    ON SP.ProductId = MS.ProductId
    AND SP.DataTypeId = MS.DataTypeId
INNER JOIN dbo.MarketSize AS MS2
    ON MS2.ProjectCode = MS.ProjectCode
    AND MS2.ProductId = MS.ProductId
    AND MS2.CountryCode = MS.CountryCode
    AND MS2.DataTypeId = MS.DataTypeId
WHERE MS.[' + @CurrentYear + N'] * MS2.[' + @CurrentYear + N'] IS NOT NULL
AND MS.OwnerTypeId = 0
AND MS.MeasureTypeId = 4
AND MS.CountryCodeId = 389
AND MS.ProductId=@ProductId
GROUP BY MS.CompanyId, SP.IndustryName, MS.[' + @CurrentYear + N'] * MS2.[' + @CurrentYear + N'] / 100, SP.ProductName)

UPDATE GBOC
    SET GBOC.KeyCategories = Final.KeyC
    FROM Sports.dbo.GlobalBrandOwnerContext AS GBOC
    INNER JOIN (   SELECT DISTINCT KeyCategories.CompanyId, KeyCategories.IndustryName, REPLACE(em_prod.dbo.StringAggregate(KeyCategories.ProductName), ',', ', ') AS KeyC
           FROM KeyCategories
           WHERE KeyCategories.Rn < 6
           GROUP BY KeyCategories.CompanyId, KeyCategories.IndustryName) AS Final
    ON Final.CompanyId = GBOC.CompanyId
    AND Final.IndustryName = GBOC.IndustryName;'
;

EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ProductId INT', @ProductId;

FETCH NEXT FROM CurrentYearCursor
INTO @ProductId, @CurrentYear;
END;

CLOSE CurrentYearCursor;
DEALLOCATE CurrentYearCursor;
```

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting?

Comment: It is 
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the `REPLACE` function in the subquery in your dynamic SQL. You have not doubled the apostrophes there. This should work fine:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @CurrentYear NVARCHAR(MAX), @ProductId NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE CurrentYearCursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT DISTINCT ProductId, CurrentYear
FROM #SubcategoryProducts;

OPEN CurrentYearCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM CurrentYearCursor
INTO @ProductId, @CurrentYear;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SELECT @SQL =
    N'
WITH KeyCategories AS
(   SELECT DISTINCT MS.CompanyId
  , SP.IndustryName
  , SP.ProductName
  , MS.[' + @CurrentYear + N'] * MS2.[' + @CurrentYear + N'] / 100 AS Size
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MS.CompanyId, SP.IndustryName
                       ORDER BY MS.[' + @CurrentYear + N'] * MS2.[' +     @CurrentYear + N'] / 100 DESC) AS Rn
FROM Sports.dbo.GlobalBrandOwnerContext AS GBOC
INNER JOIN dbo.MarketShare AS MS
    ON GBOC.CompanyId = MS.CompanyId
INNER JOIN #SubcategoryProducts AS SP
    ON SP.ProductId = MS.ProductId
    AND SP.DataTypeId = MS.DataTypeId
INNER JOIN dbo.MarketSize AS MS2
    ON MS2.ProjectCode = MS.ProjectCode
    AND MS2.ProductId = MS.ProductId
    AND MS2.CountryCode = MS.CountryCode
    AND MS2.DataTypeId = MS.DataTypeId
WHERE MS.[' + @CurrentYear + N'] * MS2.[' + @CurrentYear + N'] IS NOT NULL
AND MS.OwnerTypeId = 0
AND MS.MeasureTypeId = 4
AND MS.CountryCodeId = 389
AND MS.ProductId=@ProductId
GROUP BY MS.CompanyId, SP.IndustryName, MS.[' + @CurrentYear + N'] * MS2.[' + @CurrentYear + N'] / 100, SP.ProductName)

UPDATE GBOC
    SET GBOC.KeyCategories = Final.KeyC
    FROM Sports.dbo.GlobalBrandOwnerContext AS GBOC
    INNER JOIN (   SELECT DISTINCT KeyCategories.CompanyId, KeyCategories.IndustryName, REPLACE(em_prod.dbo.StringAggregate(KeyCategories.ProductName), '','', '', '') AS KeyC
           FROM KeyCategories
           WHERE KeyCategories.Rn < 6
           GROUP BY KeyCategories.CompanyId, KeyCategories.IndustryName) AS Final
    ON Final.CompanyId = GBOC.CompanyId
    AND Final.IndustryName = GBOC.IndustryName;'
;

EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ProductId INT', @ProductId;

FETCH NEXT FROM CurrentYearCursor
INTO @ProductId, @CurrentYear;
END;

CLOSE CurrentYearCursor;
DEALLOCATE CurrentYearCursor;
```